# Where can I get loading .png images that together make a loading spinner?

Tags: images, png

I have been googling for a while and am not finding anything useful other than .gif images. But due to the technology I am using, I need 2 or more .png images that together look like an animation.

Would anyone know where I can find or make these? Or maybe has a set handy?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just convert some images of whatever format to PNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to make an [apng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) image, although there is limited support (no webkit browsers or IE).

An alternative may be using JavaScript for the animation somehow. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736922/how-to-show-animated-image-from-png-image-using-javascript-like-gmail) looks like an interesting implementation.